# in gnu/linux unzip can one supress "excluded filename not matched" warning?

Tags: linux, cygwin

Neither the -q or -qq arguments seem to suppress this warning. ( cygwin version ) 
As it is in a script that unzips a file and the file may or may not include the undesired excluded files and since I don't want to extract them if present anyway the warning is just clutter in the output and of no consequence.

Answer (score 0):

**Unzip** dont have any flag in manual to eliminate the output of errors. The -q and -qq flags only "*perform  operations  quietly*".

Alternatively, if you are using a compatible shell, I would recommend you close the ***stderr*** and/or ***stdout***.

For close ***stdout*** you can try:

```sh
unzip ${ARGS} >&-
```

For close ***stderr*** you can try:

```sh
unzip ${ARGS} 2>&-
```

For close ***stdout*** and ***stderr***(how i believe is your case) you can try:

```sh
unzip ${ARGS} >&- 2>&-
```

With all outputs closed, nothing more will be show on terminal. If only ***stderr*** is closed, no more errors will be show on terminal.

Comment: ugh - I guess I have to spawn it and filter stdout and stderr - not pretty